# A template issue when creating a slot in Qt 4

Tags: c++, qt, templates

I'm trying to create a class for signal/slot connection (old syntax, Qt 4.8) and I am doing something wrong as I keep receiving a template error: `invalid declaration of member template in local class`... That has obviously something to do with the `Q_OBJECT` macro... What should I do? Here is a modeled program:

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtCore>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  QWidget mw;
  mw.setWindowTitle("Main Window");
  mw.resize(400, 400);
  mw.show();

    QLabel label ("Enter something:", &mw);
    label.setAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter);
    label.show();

    QLineEdit line (&mw);
    line.show();

    QString a = line.text();

    QTextEdit text (&mw);
    text.show();

    class MyObject : public QObject
    {
       Q_OBJECT       /* the problem is somewhere here... */

       public:
       QTextEdit text;
       QString a;

       public slots:
       void onClicked() {
          text.setText(a);
      }
    };

    QPushButton btn ("Convert", &mw);
    QObject::connect(
      &btn,
      SIGNAL(clicked()),
      this,
      SLOT(onClicked()));
    btn.show();

  QVBoxLayout layout_mw;

  layout_mw.addWidget(&label);
  layout_mw.addWidget(&line);
  layout_mw.addWidget(&btn);
  layout_mw.addWidget(&text);

  mw.setLayout(&layout_mw);

  return app.exec();

}
```

Comment: just move `MyObject ` class to own header file and source file. Then moc tool will be able to create needed meta data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt's MOC can process neither nested classes nor local classes. You will have to move the class definition outside `main`. [The documentation](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/moc.html#limitations) only mentions nested classes, but the limitation does apply to local classes too.